# View SQL code for job in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I want to view the SQL code that is executed for a particular job in SQL Server Management Studio.

Specifically, I have a screen that looks like this:

[image]

If I double click it I get a screen that looks like this:

[image]

That is not really helpful. I want to see the actual code that is running and possibly modify it.

I am a long time developer but new to Windows so please give an answer that uses terminology that I can see on the screen.

[EDIT] If I click the edit button on the first screen I get the same screen as if I double click it.  There is a `DTSRun` command and some jibberish which is not anything I would expect to edit.

[EDIT] I followed these instructions to decode the encrypted command line:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/vipulshah/2007/03/12/how-to-identify-which-dts-package-is-being-called-by-scheduled-job/

Then I could see the command line looks like this:

`DTSRun /S "192.168.2.1" /U "sa" /P "changeme" /N "Delete AppErrors"`

I then searched the entire computer for a filename that contained AppErrors in the name.  I did not find one.

So I am getting closer, but how do I find what that is executing?

Comment: You should click Edit button on the first window.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SQL code in this job/task, because the task type is "Operating system (CmdExec)", i.e. this is not a SQL query, but starting of Windows executable file. There will be SQL code for step type "Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)":

[image]

What you see in you job step, is execution of SSIS package, which is encrypted. For more information about DTSRun command, take a look at this article - [SQL Server DTS command line utility](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1007/sql-server-dts-command-line-utility/).

Answer (score 0):

I almost solved my problem like this:

A.
I followed the instructions here to decode the encrypted command line:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/vipulshah/2007/03/12/how-to-identify-which-dts-package-is-being-called-by-scheduled-job/

Which amounted to:

1. Copy the DTSRUN line (everything including the DTSRUN)
2. Open a Windows Command Line window
3. Paste the DTSRUN line into the CMD window.
4. To the end of the line, add /!X /!C
   /!X = do not execute /!C = copy results onto Windows Clipboard
5. Run the command
6. Open Notepad
7. Click Edit>Paste
   that will paste the actual command into Notepad and it will show the name of the package.

B.
I observed that the command line looked like this:

`DTSRun /S "192.168.2.1" /U "sa" /P "changeme" /N "Delete AppErrors"`

C.
Then I follow the instructions here to find the code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc645945(v=sql.105)

which amounted to:

1. In Object Explorer, expand the Management folder.
2. Expand the Legacy subfolder.
3. Expand the Data Transformation Services subfolder to show packages.

D.
I right click on it and choose Open.  I get this error:

[image]

I should not have to install anything because the person who put this on the machine must have been able to edit it.  (this person is completely unavailable so I can't ask him).  The reason I need access to it is that we are upgrading the machine.